# on the application of FLT

Tags: number-theory

i saw a problem which is a generalization of Beals conjecture,here 
[sinha conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinha_Conjecture_Prize),it holds a open prize of US$150,000, for the proof or disproof of a mathematical proposition . The award money was tripled on January 11, 2010.

and coming to my doubt,this is a starting step,
i saw that the there is some deep relation between the FLT,and this thing,i think we can proceed proving ,as the FLT is for the same power ,i mean its of the form 
$x^a+y^a=z^a$ for some $a$,all the exponents being same, and this conjecture is of the form $x^a+y^b=z^c$,i think these two form the two sides of the argument,i mean that all the things that hold good for fermats equation may not hold good for $x^a+y^b=z^c$,so by contradiction or by inverse argument can we prove further,

what more is the relationship between FLT and sinha conjecture,and is there an intervention of taniyama shimura conjecture,relating to sinha conjecture,

thank you

Answer (score 2):

At the given link, it's claimed Sinha has a proof of "Beal's conjecture," but won't ever publish it. Right. Anyway, I'd recommend having a look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28764/status-of-beal-tijdeman-zagier-conjecture to see what's been done about this circle of conjectures.

Comment: but that did not satisfy my hunger of getting the answer,thats completely different from it

Comment: @iyengar, it's hard to know what you mean by "the answer." The Sinha conjecture is closely related to the Beal Prize problem, right? The MO thread gives links to work that has been done on the Beal Prize problem. You can follow that up, and see for yourself whether Taniyama-Shimura has had any bearing on the work and, by implication, whether it is likely to have any bearing on Sinha's question.